# how do I keep a reference to a class object conforming to a protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, factory-pattern, swift-protocols

Perhaps I'm still thinking in an Objective-C kind of way.  I'd like to register classes to be used in a factory pattern.  The classes conform to a protocol such as:

```swift
protocol URLNavigation: class {
  static func canHandle(url: URL) -> Bool
  static func instantiate(with url: URL) -> UIViewController?
  var url: URL? { get set }
}
```

and then in my Factory class have something like:

`var registeredTypes: [UIViewController.self & URLNavigation]`

But I know the line above is incorrect.  I'm trying to keep a references to class objects that will be used to instantiate instances of those classes.

And am also wondering how I would instantiate these using an element in this 'registeredTypes' array.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to accomplish.  Perhaps there's another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

`var registeredTypes: [(UIViewController & URLNavigation).Type]`.

Comment: how to I add to the array?  I do not want to add an instance of a class.  I want to register a class.

Comment: @horseshoe7 can you provide more code, how do you want to register a class?

Comment: ```
class MySubclassImplementingProtocol: UIViewController, URLNavigation { /*... */  }

// elsewhere...
self.registeredTypes.append(MySubclassImplementingProtocol.self)
```

Comment: I'm hoping you have Objective-C experience and can see how I'm probably thinking in an objective-C way, so you'll know how to 'translate'.